# st terminal: copy on select and right mouse click to paste

Tags: linux, x11, mouse, clipboard, suckless-terminal

https://st.suckless.org/patches/clipboard/ makes mousewheel to select and paste but I need copy on select of left mouse and then right mouse click to paste.

and to extend, ctrl-v to paste.

I use xorg, archlinux.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mouse release handling

The routine that turns a mouse event into a paste is `brelease()` in `x.c`:

```
void
brelease(XEvent *e)
{
        if (IS_SET(MODE_MOUSE) && !(e->xbutton.state & forceselmod)) {
                mousereport(e);
                return;
        }

        if (e->xbutton.button == Button2)
                selpaste(NULL);
        else if (e->xbutton.button == Button1)
                mousesel(e, 1);
}
```

If you want the right button to paste, instead of the middle one, simply change `Button2` to `Button3` then recompile:

```
            if (e->xbutton.button == Button3)
```

## Keyboard shortcut definitions

Keyboard shortcuts are in the `shortcuts` array in `config.h`.  Clipboard-paste is already mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>:

```
static Shortcut shortcuts[] = {
    /* mask                 keysym          function        argument */
...
    { TERMMOD,              XK_V,           clippaste,      {.i =  0} },
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> already has a special meaning in some shells and editors, so you might not want the terminal to intercept it, and prefer to use the existing shortcut.  But if you're really determined to have this new shortcut, you'll have to add/change the line as follows:

```
    { ControlMask,          XK_v,           clippaste,      {.i =  0} },
```

Note the `XK_v` now has a lowercase "v", because it's without <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, but what about copy-on-select?

Comment: I get copy-on-select without making any changes.  Have you applied other patches?

Comment: You're right, I missed that one. Work like a charm.

Comment: @JiggyNaga: I have another question, should I create new one? But I'll post here first, I try to copy multiple lines of text from firefox and then try to open `vim` in st terminal then press `ctrl-v` but it paste the whole into one line, I expect lines are speparated by newline `\b` as the original. How to do that with st terminal?

Comment: I mean `\b` --> `\n`

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a separate question, and the problem may be in Firefox rather than `st`.

Comment: Please refer new question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471643/256195

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @JigglyNaga, but nowdays (2022 Aug) this config can be done in config.def.h / config.h:

```
/*
 * Internal mouse shortcuts.
 * Beware that overloading Button1 will disable the selection.
 */
static MouseShortcut mshortcuts[] = {
        /* mask                 button   function        argument       release */
        { XK_ANY_MOD,           Button3, selpaste,       {.i = 0},      1 },
        { ShiftMask,            Button4, ttysend,        {.s = "\033[5;2~"} },
        { XK_ANY_MOD,           Button4, ttysend,        {.s = "\031"} },
        { ShiftMask,            Button5, ttysend,        {.s = "\033[6;2~"} },
        { XK_ANY_MOD,           Button5, ttysend,        {.s = "\005"} },
};
```

Mind I've changed Button2 to Button3 for selpaste - this is what you want to do if you want a paste function to be triggered on right mouse button click.

Gosh, I love st. It's the only terminal which can be easily configured like that.